# Skip printing if file is empty

Tags: ruby

I want to print values using this code:

```
p trx_types
```

This prints a list which sometimes is empty and I get NilClass

How I can skip printing if the content is empty?

Comment: Just use some ruby: `p trx_types if trx_types`

Comment: Also, to be pedantic, "empty list" and "nil" are two very different things.

Comment: Can you show me check for both @SergioTulentsev?

Comment: If `p trx_types` prints `NilClass`, then nothing is "empty". The only way for that to happen is if `trx_types == NilClass`. Why are you storing the class of `nil`? I suspect you don't actually know what or where the problem is in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using .nil? should solve it

```
p trx_types unless trx_types.nil?
```

Answer (score -1):

What is `trx_types`? And it depends what you mean by "empty". (I would be able to provide a clearer, more succinct answer if the question is also clarified!)

If you **only** want to skip cases where `trx_types == nil`, then you could do:

```
p trx_types unless trx_types.nil?
```

Or (almost) equivalently, you can also skip cases where `trx_types == false` by doing:

```
p trx_types if trx_types
```

If you want to skip cases where `trx_types == ""`, or `trx_types == []`, or similar (again, I ask: what *is* `trx_types`??) then you may wish to do:

```
p trx_types unless trx_types.empty?
```

...Or to do the above whilst also gracefully handling (and skipping) `nil` cases then perhaps:

```
p trx_types unless trx_types&.empty?
```

Comment: It's a pity that nil doesn't respond to `empty?`. Rails fixed that with `blank?`